# Script won't execute within NextJS page?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Hoping someone could please provide me with some advice regarding a problem I've run into in NextJS?

I have some JavaScript code that works properly within a plain html file, but for whatever reason won't work properly in NextJS.

As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EXNu.jpg), it gets stuck on Loading when it should pull in user info from an API.

My code inside my NextJS file looks like this:

```
import ArticleList from '../components/ArticleList'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function Home({ articles }) {
    return (
    <div>

      <Head>
        <title>MFT Power BI - Next.js</title>
        <meta name='keywords' content='test,test,test'/>
       
      </Head>

    

<>
    <Script
      src="../components/scripts/reportSearch.js"
      strategy="beforeInteractive"
    />
   
  </>

      <div>
      <ArticleList articles={articles} />
    </div>

    </div>
    )
  }
  
 export const getStaticProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=6`)
   const articles = await res.json()

   return {
     props: {
       articles,
     },
   }
 }
```

The code inside reportSearch.js is:

```
const result = document.getElementById('result')
const filter = document.getElementById('filter')
const listItems = []

getData()

filter.addEventListener('input', (e) => filterData(e.target.value))

async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=50')

    const { results } = await res.json()

    // Clear result
    result.innerHTML = ''

    results.forEach(user => {
        const li = document.createElement('li')

        listItems.push(li)

        li.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${user.picture.large}" alt="${user.name.first}">
            <div className={user-info}>
                <h4>${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}</h4>
                <p>${user.location.city}, ${user.location.country}</p>
                <p class="text-dark">${user.gender}</p>
            </div>
        `

        result.appendChild(li)
    })
}

function filterData(searchTerm) {
    listItems.forEach(item => {
        if(item.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
            item.classList.remove('hide')
        } else {
            item.classList.add('hide')
        }
    })
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any relevant errors in the dev tools console or network tab?

Comment: @phuzi I get the following errors: https://imgur.com/a/1BVAjLd

Comment: Please add the text of the errors to the question, rather than an image that not everyone will be able to see.

Comment: You're using Next.js with React now, so why still use plain DOM manipulation and linking a plain script?

Comment: @catgirlkelly I'm still super new to coding so I thought this would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: To be perfectly blunt, this is kind of like using a tool box, but still hand-screwing screws in. You've got the power of React available but still use vanilla. I'd advise learning a little React and trying to convert your script to use that instead.